# map iteration, how to get only one item per time with map function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, iteration, map-function

I have  question about iteration through json data with `$.map` Below you can see my code , my goal it's append only 1 title per time with iterration (1 item 1st title; 2 title 2nd title; and so on) but right now I got all of them , when I use `return $('.card-title').append(post.title[i]);` I got letter from each  item , can anybody help me with advise please , Thank you .

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
    dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function(data){
    console.log(data);
    $.map(data, function(post ,i){
        return $('.card-title').append(post.title);
    });
 });
});
```

Comment: I don't see any problem with your code: https://jsfiddle.net/rxnkdxeo/

Comment: What is the output you get from `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))`?

Comment: I got all of them but when i try to append post.title to element all items are appended instead I want append just 1 item per time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.eq()` to reference a specific index of the jQuery collection

```
$(".card-title").eq(i).append(post.title);
```

or substitute using `.append(function)` for `$.map()`

```
$(".card-title").append(function(i, el) {
  return data[i].post.title
});
```